# Spark ml basic operation in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have `Dataset <Row> dataset;` and want to perform some basic operation on it.
**For Example:-** Suppose I have 3 columns **"Id","Name","Age"**
and data for these columns. I want to perform these below operation on this dataset based on **Name** column 
[1] Remove white space from Name column
[2] Remove number  from Name column
[3] Remove special character from Name column

I am using java8, Apache-Spark and Apache-Spark-ml library

Please suggest best way to do this.

Comment: Use `regexp_replace()`. How is this related to Spark ML?

Comment: @vdep I am new in java and Spark, so for me it is difficult to understand these, like  how to iterate dataset then find columns and perform operations

Comment: @vdep If you guide in this will be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regexp_replace()` to replace whitespaces, numbers & special characters. (Essentially retain only letters).

```
List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>() {{
    add(RowFactory.create("validName"));
    add(RowFactory.create("name with whitespace    "));
    add(RowFactory.create("name with numbers 1234"));
    add(RowFactory.create("name with special chars !@#$%"));

}};

StructField[] structFields = new StructField[]{
        new StructField("Name", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
};

//create sample data
Dataset<Row> input = spark().createDataFrame(rows, new StructType(structFields));
input.withColumn("cleanedName", functions.regexp_replace(functions.col("Name"),"[^a-zA-Z]+", "")).show(100, false);
```

cleanedName column has the expected values:

```
+-----------------------------+--------------------+
|Name                         |cleanedName         |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+
|validName                    |validName           |
|name with whitespace         |namewithwhitespace  |
|name with numbers 1234       |namewithnumbers     |
|name with special chars !@#$%|namewithspecialchars|
+-----------------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: I need one more suggestion if I want to do this on multiple columns how we can do this

Comment: Yes, use the same function(s) under `.withColumn()` to apply for other columns